# RelativeLayout in ArrayAdapter adds a line in bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-relativelayout

I'm using a relative layout in custom arrayadapter to show images plus text ans some buttons.

When i test the app see a space between those layout:

Can you please see what's causing this?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cardImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_text_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_text_padding"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/card_text_size"


        />
 
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_right_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/card_options_padding_bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/card_options_padding_left"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/card_options_padding_left">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/likeButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/card_options_button_dimen"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_options_button_dimen"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_favorite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/likeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/card_options_text_size" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be the ListView's default divider, which you can change by setting the `divider` attribute on the `ListView` element in your layout xml. To remove it altogether, set it to `@null`.

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:divider="@null"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

change android:layout_width="**fill_parent**" to **wrap_content**

fill_parent is deprecated and renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher

that line you see is maybe for diveder of ListView